# Assign SQL Query result to a variable

Tags: sql, vb6

Currently am working on a vb6.0 project and using SQLExpress as my backend database server. 
I have written the following query to get the number of employees per department, the query runs successfully in query window of SQLServer and returns desired result. I am trying to use the same query in my vb 6.0 form and get the result in a local variable say Temp.

But I am not able assign the query result to variable Temp. I am struck and not able to move forward.

```
SQL = "select dbo.tbl_employee_master.dept_id, COUNT(emp_id) as '# of employees' from dbo.tbl_employee_master where dbo.tbl_employee_master.dept_id IN ( select dbo.tbl_employee_master.dept_id from dbo.tbl_employee_master Group BY dbo.tbl_employee_master.dept_id HAVING dbo.tbl_employee_master.dept_id = '" & cmb_dept.Text & "') Group BY dbo.tbl_employee_master.dept_id"

connectDB
Dim Temp As String
Temp = RS.GetString
lbl_last_id.Caption = Temp
connClose
txt_emp_code.Text = lbl_comp_short.Caption & "-" & lbl_dept_short_form.Caption & "-" & lbl_last_id.Caption
```

I am writing above code in combo box LostFocus event, so that when user selects a dept from dropdown list and moves to next field on the form, the above query gets executed and fetchs the number of employees for that particular dept.

Comment: Showing the SQL is not enough to help you. [edit] your question to add the vb6 code where you are executing the sql and trying to apply the result to `Temp`.

Comment: If you show your code someone will probabaly show you what is wrong. The generic answer is, `intVariable = recordset.Fields(0).Value`.

Comment: code updated please check

Answer (score 0):

With little bit of work around with RecordSet properties, I am able to fetch the number of employees per dept as below.

```
SQL = "select COUNT(emp_id) as '# of employees' from dbo.tbl_employee_master where dbo.tbl_employee_master.dept_id IN ( select dbo.tbl_employee_master.dept_id from dbo.tbl_employee_master Group BY dbo.tbl_employee_master.dept_id HAVING dbo.tbl_employee_master.dept_id = '" & cmb_dept.Text & "') Group BY dbo.tbl_employee_master.dept_id"
connectDB
Dim Temp As String
Temp = RS.GetString
lbl_last_id.Caption = Temp

connClose
txt_emp_code.Text = lbl_comp_short.Caption & "-" & lbl_dept_short_form.Caption & "-" & lbl_last_id.Caption
```

if you notice, I made slight changes to my SQL query as well so it returns only number of records, the same is assigned to a variable with the help of Recordset.GetString

```
Temp = RS.GetString
```

Thank you for your comments @c-pound Guru and jac